# Print logo image using cups API

Tags: c++, printing, cups

I am able to print using Cups, I can send data to a printer using `cupsPrintFile` and also i can write into the printer using `cupsWriteRequestData`.

But I can not figure out how to print an image using the CUPS API, what I really need is to print a page with logo in the header and text data in page body.

What do you think about that ?